# Problems with Identity Server 3

Tags: c#, angularjs, identityserver3

We are having a bit of trouble with putting Identity Server 3 into our applications.

Currently we have a WebApi with NHibernate to connect to our Oracle databases.
We use angularjs on our front-end, and call the controller methods with ajax.
An old coleague, used identity server on one of the applications he made, but, he configured Identity server to get Windows Credentials (Since we're in a corporate AD), but recently we're making an external website, that will have a login and password, and we would like to use identity server as our authentication and autorization.

I have looked into examples on their github and other articles(like [this one](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-using-ASPNET-Identity)), but I wasn't able to connect to the IS3 to authenticate, it would give me a 403.14 error.

Building and running gives no error, but I can't seem to access Identity Server 3.

Here's the startup

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    try
    {
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "Identity Server",
                EnableWelcomePage = false,
                RequireSsl = false,
                IssuerUri = string.Format("{0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdServerEndPoint"]),
                SigningCertificate = Certificate.Load(),
                Factory = Factory.Configure("MyConStr")
            });
        });
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        LogCore.LogError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you added more detail regarding "couldn't get it to work" and "can't seem to access it's methods". In general, enabling logging will be a big benefit to you if you are encountering problems.

Comment: The relevance to the nhibernate tag is unclear - I don't think you should tag your question for every library your application uses unless you think it's actually relevant to the problem.

Comment: I would start by enabling logging in Identity Server which is very easy to do: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html

Comment: Turns out my client was trying to scam me, so I ended up dropping the development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your IdentityServerOptions.

```
LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
{
  EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
  WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true,
  EnableHttpLogging = true,
  EnableKatanaLogging = true
}
```

You should see a mud-glorious amount of really valuable debugging information. This usually tells me what I've done wrong. If you are not seeing the logging coming to your output, check out https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html

Comment: Thanks, now I only need to find the reason I can't connect. Hahaha. But this will help out a lot

Comment: Another trick you might want to try is to checkout the JavaScript Walk Through sample project. Event if you don't plan on using JavaScript authentication, I find it to be a great debugging tool. Get it running with the Identity Server project in the solution. Then once you have that working, edit the settings in index.html to point to _your_ Identity Server instance, making sure that you use the correct client information. That way, you are not debugging the client side and the server side at the same time.

Comment: Hey Felipe, why don't you post the log?